# Error: (functionName) already defined in Algorithms.obj

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
1>GameWinMain.obj : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl BPredicate(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?BPredicate@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) already defined in Algorithms.obj
1>C:\Algorithms.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I'm getting the latter when trying to declare a function in the header.
I'm not sure what's causing this, everything has include guards.
Funny thing is: if I define the function in the header as inline, it compiles.
Can anyone help?

See code Below:

***Algorithms.h***

```
#pragma once

//...other code

bool BPredicate(const string& a, const string& b){
    string::const_iterator it;
    UINT numA = 0;
    UINT numB = 0;
    for (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        if((*it) == ' ') {
            if (*(it-1) != ' ') {
                ++numA;
            }
        }
    }
    for (it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it) {
        if((*it) == ' ') {
            if (*(it-1) != ' ') {
                ++numB;
            }
        }
    }

    return (numA < numB);
}
```

***GameWinMain.h***

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow);
```

***GameWinMain.cpp***

```
#include "GameWinMain.h"
#include "GameEngine.h"
#include "Algorithms.h" 

#define GAME_ENGINE (GameEngine::GetSingleton())

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    if (GAME_ENGINE == NULL) return FALSE; 

    GAME_ENGINE->SetGame(new Algorithms()); 

    return GAME_ENGINE->Run(hInstance, iCmdShow); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2005: already defined - C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not define functions in headers like that. Either mark it as `static` or `inline` or it will be defined in all source files where you include the header.

If you want to use the function from several source files, only *declare* it in the header:

```
bool BPredicate(const string& a, const string& b);
```

(Note the semicolon and no function body.)

Then define the function in one of your source files.

Comment: Why can I define methods of classes in the header file like that, then? Wouldn't they also be included in every source file that includes them? 

Is this only the case when I include it in the source file or also in another header?

And why does static or inline prevent this?

Comment: @xcrypt There is a difference between a _declaration_ and a _definition_. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1410632/440558) SO answer for details. A function that is `inline` or `static` is only available in the source file it is defined in, it's not exported to other source file. The drawback of doing this in a header file is that the function machine code will be duplicated in all object files made from sources including the header.