# tracking down LNK2005: "already defined"

Tags: c++, windows

I have been working on a program in windows VC++ 2008. I started by having all of my code in .cpp files (just to get everything working), and now breaking things into .h, and .cpp files. when I compile I get a mountain of LNK2005 errors stating that:

```
Object.obj : error LNK2005: "__thiscall thing::thing(args)" already defined in otherObject.obj
```

while I was making the original program I kept getting errors of undeclared identifier, and so I gave a include directive to satisfy that. now when I am breaking everything up into separate .cpp, and .h files I get all of this. which place do I start looking (Object, otherObject, or thing), or somewhere else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2005: already defined - C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have definition for `thing::thing(args)` in two Translation Units(TU), which violates the One Definition Rule(ODR) and hence the error.
The linker exactly tells you which TU's are involved: `otherObject.obj` and `Object.obj`.

Start looking in to `otherObject.cpp` and `Object.cpp` and the headers which are included in these two `cpp` files. It is most likely that you have defined your constructor `thing::thing(args)` in header file and including that header file in both these `cpp` files results in multiple definitions.

**Suggested Solution:**

You cannot define the constructor in header file, You need to add it to your `cpp` file along with other member functions of the class. If you must add the definition of constructor to header you should mark it `inline`, given that You have not shown your code I don't see any reason to apply the second approach.

Comment: its not just the constructor, but seems like all of the methods, so do I mark them all inline

Comment: @gardian06: Can you not just *declare* the methods in the header file and put the *definitions* in the `cpp` file? That is the most logical way to do this.

Comment: that's what all this is about. i moved the class, members, and stubs in the header, and left the implementation in the cpp putting resolution operators as convention

Comment: not sure how "safe" this is, but adding inline to all the included methods cleared up all of the errors

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in your question, I bet that the method is defined in a header file but not marked inline. This then causes duplicate symbol linker errors. Try marking hte method inline or moving the definition to a source (`.C`) file.

Comment: its not just the constructor, but seems like all of the methods, so do I mark them all inline