# Error lnk2005 already defined in .obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, namespaces, function-definition

There are many question about this error. But they are related to only a single variable.

**test.h**

```
namespace World
{
    enum Objects
    {
        TERRAIN = 1,
        BOX = 2,
        SPHERE = 4,
        CAPSULE = 8

    };  

    void WorldObjects2(unsigned int mask)
    {
      .......
    }
}

void test();
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

void test()
{
    .......
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run these code on visual stduio 2013, it throws an error. It says that `error LNK2005: "void __cdecl World::WorldObjects2(unsigned int)" (?WorldObjects2@World@@YAXI@Z) already defined in main.obj`. How can I correct this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2005: already defined - C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your project has two definitions of function `WorldObjects2` : one is in the compilation unit `test.cpp` and other is in the compilation unit `main.cpp` because the header where the function is defined is included in these two cpp files.

Either use function specifier `inline`

```
inline void WorldObjects2(unsigned int mask)
{
    .......
}
```

Or move the function definition to some cpp file leaving only a function declaration (without its definition) in the header.

Another approach is to make the function as having the internal linkage. For example you could add keyword static

```
static void WorldObjects2(unsigned int mask)
{
    .......
}
```

or could place the function in an unnamed namespace within the given namespace.

```
namespace World
{
    // ...
    namespace
    {
        void WorldObjects2(unsigned int mask)
        {
            .......
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you know why the include guard does not work for this case?

Comment: @Timo It works. Simply there are two separate compilation units each of them includes the header.

Comment: Reading up on the subject, it appears that `static` is also an option. Found an explanation here: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?285375-inline-function-vs-static-function

Comment: @Timo  It depands on whether you want that this function would be static.:)

Comment: You're definitely right, but I felt that it was a good thing to mention this additional option. Making the function static also fixes this example, but it might not be the right solution in another project.

Comment: @Timo I did it as you are advising.