# Error LNK2005: function already defined in MyForm.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a windows form application in Visual Studio C++, but I get this errors after compiling, for each function:

> error LNK2005: function already defined in MyForm.obj

These are my files:

Source.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]//leave this as is
void main() {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew Project1::MyForm);
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Header.h"

namespace Project1 {
    //codes of te form
}
```

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n, m;
int size1, size2;
//My functions here
```

So how can I fix errors?

Comment: Are you declaring and implementing the function in Header.h?

Comment: That Source.cpp is not C++.  You need to straighten out your language tags.

Comment: You are using C++ in a project that isn't C++. Windows Forms can only be used with C++/CLI. Hard to fathom why you, as the author, doesn't know, what programming language you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c

Comment: @jpo38 Here is my Header.h:http://paste.white-crow.ir/view/661/2y10ROuR9ANfhSl

Comment: Why are you writing functions within your header file?  You have multiple versions of these functions when you placed them in the header, and included the header in multiple source files.

Comment: @AliMahdavifar: The check my answer below!

Comment: There is not enough here to answer your question.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare and implement a function in a header file (Header.h) and if this file gets included twice, then you'll most likely will get a `function already defined` error at some point.

This can be fixed by either:

- Moving function implementation to a source (cpp) file and only keep it's declaration in the header (h) file
- Make the function `inline` (if it is acceptable), that will remove the error

Comment: *"your code looks more like C# than C++"* - It's C++/CLI. C# doesn't use `::` as a scope resolution operator, and doesn't have the `gcnew` keyword either.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK removed my comment. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't change much. You are talking about C++-specific rules, but the OP isn't using C++. This is really just guesswork. It may be right, but you should really write a comment asking for clarification first.

Comment: @jpo38 Thanks a lot! My problem solved by making all functions `inline`.