# method already defined (template class)

Tags: c++, templates, object, linker-errors

I am getting the error "method already defined in class.obj" on ALL my methods,
I've seen that some of the solutions include separating the class into a header and a .cpp file but it's not possible in this case.

Any help will be much appreciated.

this is my h file: http://pastebin.com/k46JEQBH

the cpp has:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "poly.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your definitions are in your header, and it's probably being included in multiple .cpp files. Each .cpp file is a new translation unit. Imagine you compile each .cpp file one at a time. For each .cpp file that includes your header, it will be the first time that header is encountered, `POLY_H` will not have been defined yet. Declarations are allowed to appear multiple times, but definitions are not. Move your definitions to a separate .cpp file and everything should work.

Edit: Keeping the definition in your header is necessary and allowed for template classes, but your class is not templated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your usage of #pragma once? What compiler are you using?

And have you tried using include guards instead to see if that resolves the errors? For example:

```
#ifndef POLY_H
#define POLY_H
//your code minus the pragma once
#endif //POLY_H
```

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015. I tried your example but to no avail.

Comment: After looking around, it appears that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c) will help you. After testing your problem locally, making everything (Including constructors) inline, it built successfully.

Comment: Although I'm curious, why can't you separate the code into a hpp/cpp file?

Comment: I can't declare everything as inline as it will damage the quality of the code.
I also cannot separate it into a cpp file as its a template class

Comment: Then would you be able to do away with the cpp file completely? Or go the route of making an h file and a tpp file with the declarations, and including the tpp file at the end of the h file?