# Already defined LNK2005 (C++)

Tags: c++, class, include, multiple-definition-error

I've got LNK2005 error when compiling my solution. It says

```
"public: class Vector3 const__cdecl Vector3::operator+=(double const &)" (??_0Vector3@@QEAA?BV0@AEBN@Z) already defined in Game.obg            file: GameObject.obj
"public: class Vector3 const__cdecl Vector3::operator+=(double const &)" (??_0Vector3@@QEAA?BV0@AEBN@Z) already defined in Game.obg            file: Main.obj
"public: class Vector3 const__cdecl Vector3::operator+=(double const &)" (??_0Vector3@@QEAA?BV0@AEBN@Z) already defined in Game.obg            file: MainWindow.obj
"public: class Vector3 const__cdecl Vector3::operator+=(double const &)" (??_0Vector3@@QEAA?BV0@AEBN@Z) already defined in Game.obg            file: Transform.obj
"public: class Vector3 const__cdecl Vector3::operator+=(double const &)" (??_0Vector3@@QEAA?BV0@AEBN@Z) already defined in Game.obg            file: Vector3.obj
```

My solution is organized as below:

*Game.h includes GameObject.h and other things*

*GameObject.h includes Transform.h and Component.h*

*Component.h includes all components headers, like Rigidbody.h*

*Transform.h includes Vector3.h*

*Vector3.h includes cmath*

In Game.h there is this:

```
#include "GameObject.h"
// other includes
class Game
{
public:
    Game( class MainWindow& wnd );
    // other things
private:
    MainWindow& wnd;
    // other things
}
// other things again
```

So the question is: what I'm doing wrong?
PS: I've tried to comment all the code in Game.cpp to see what happens, but without success

EDIT: I've resolved it by moving "Vector3::operator+=" definition from Vector3.h to Vector3.cpp... but don't know why it works now, anyone knows? (Vector3.h don't have include guard but it has #pragma once, Vector3.cpp don't have neither include guard nor #pragma once)

Comment: It is hard to tell _exactly_ what the problem is with your code, but it is likely you are breaking the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error LNK2005: already defined - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622229/error-lnk2005-already-defined-c)

Comment: Did you add include guards in your headers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard